How to automatically generate quarto documents based on information from a dataframe?
Im planning to build a quarto website and I would like to automatically generate qmd files within my website directory filled with information from a dataframe.
rating <- 1:4
           animal <- c('koala', 'hedgehog', 'sloth', 'panda')
           country <- c('Australia', 'Italy', 'Peru', 'China')
           avg_sleep_hours <- c(21, 18, 17, 10)
           super_sleepers <- data.frame(rating, animal, country, avg_sleep_hours)
           print(super_sleepers)

So if this is my dataframe, I would like to get one qmd file for each animal (koala.qmd, hedgehog.qmd,...). And within this quarto documents, I would like to fill in the data iaccording to a predefined layout, namely at specific positions within the document.
A simple example for the koala.qmd would be
---
Koala
---
# header

text ... Koala... text ... Australia ... text ... 21 ... text...

Does anyone know to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Seems to be a use case for parameters.
